# react leaflet - MapContainer only get initial value of parent useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I have a very weird scenario using `react leaflet`

I have a parent component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef} from "react";
import Locate from "locate";

export default function Chat (props) {

    const [allowLocation, setAllowLocation] = useState(true)


    function handleUpdate(p){
    console.log(allowLocation)
    if(allowLocation){
    console.log("update location")
    }

    }
    
    function handleShareLocation(){
    if(allowLocation){
        setAllowLocation(false)
    }else{
        setAllowLocation(true)
    }
    }

return(
<div>
  <button onClick={handleShareLocation}>share location</button>
  <Locate  parentUpdate={(p)=>{handleUpdate(p)}} />
</div>
)
}
```

Basically, The parent component has an `allowLocation` variable to control if user permission to show map to opposite party(it's a chat app).

and `Locate` component(child):

```
export default function Locate (props){
    
  function handleMarkerPosition(pos){
    props.parentUpdate(pos)
  }

  return(
  <div>
  <button onClick={e=>{handleMarkerPosition("test")}}>click test</button>
  <MapContainer 
    whenCreated={m => {mapRef.current = m}} center={[lat, lng]} zoom={16} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"/>
    <DraggableMarker location={[lat, lng]} markerupdateposition={(pos)=>handleMarkerPosition(pos)} />
  </MapContainer>
  </div>
)}


 
function DraggableMarker(props) {
   ...
}
```

1. If I click on `click test` button, it will call `handleMarkerPosition` function, that will call `props.parentUpdate`, and trigger `handleUpdate` from parent component. Then, it will trigger according to the `allowLocation`(this is expected behavior)
2. but if I drag the `DraggableMarker` around, which using the same `handleMarkerPosition` function, will always get the initial value of `allowLocation` from parent, no matter how I already change the value in the parent.

Why is this happening? I only check `allowLocation` at parent component, but somehow the child component always remember the initial value of its parent component. Moreover, `1` and `2` are sharing the same function.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'm finding this question very confusing.  The button calls `handleMarkerPosition`, which calls `parentUpdate`, which calls `handleUpdate`, which does...nothing?  Also, what is `DraggableMarker`, and what is `parentupdateposition`??

Comment: @SethLutske Actually `andleUpdate` supposed to `POST` user location, I took it out to simplify the debug. I change `parentupdateposition` to `markerupdateposition`, which is the `DraggableMarker`tell `Locate` user done dragging and provide the latest location.